# When user name is a number, what is the correct name for label

Tags: login, username

When user name is a number, what is the correct name for label?

When we use an email + password to login, the label can be named USERNAME or EMAIL.

But in my case, the username is a number - actually the id of employee in the company, something like 856974.

I think "user name" is not correct to label.

Suggestions?

Comment: How is it called when users *recieve* their number?

Answer (score 4):

**User ID**

**Employee ID**

**ID**

**Account ID**

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

Either **User number** (Something along the lines of Social Security number, or Roll Number)

or **User Id** (something along the lines of Employee Id)

I am assuming that the question is in the context of a registration form, not profile view